# Example Thread Java

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, button, listener

Why does not work the first example? while the second one with thread works? And I don't understand what is the use of the sleep. It is a counter that start after press the start button . If I press the INC-DEC button it must change the counter trend. So it increases or decreases the counter.

Contatore.java without thread

```
public class Contatore extends JFrame {
    private int count;
    private boolean runFlag;
    private JButton onOff;
    private JButton start;
    public Contatore() {
        runFlag = true;
        count = 0;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        onOff = new JButton("INCR-DECR");
        add(onOff);
        onOff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runFlag = !runFlag;
            }
        });
        start = new JButton("START");
        add(start);
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                start.setEnabled(false);
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }(runFlag) count++;
                    else count--;
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            }
        });
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Contatore f = new Contatore();
    }
}
```

ContatoreRisolto.java with Thread

```
public class ContatoreRisolto extends JFrame {
    private boolean runFlag;
    private JButton onOff;
    private JButton start;
    public ContatoreRisolto() {
        runFlag = true;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        onOff = new JButton("INCR-DECR");
        add(onOff);
        onOff.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                runFlag = !runFlag;
            }
        });
        start = new JButton("START");
        add(start);
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                start.setEnabled(false);
                Counter c = new Counter();
                c.start();
            }
        });
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ContatoreRisolto f = new ContatoreRisolto();
    }
    class Counter extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                if (runFlag) count++;
                else count--;
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread.sleep(500)` Method completely stops the main program thread for 500 milliseconds. Because you are doing everything in a single thread in the first example, the program just freezes because you're calling `Thread.sleep(500)` repeatedly.

In the second example, the main thread keeps running and your Counter thread sleeps. Therefore your program will not freeze and everything works.

Comment: thank you , but i still don't understand why the thread counter must sleep for 500 milliseconds.

Comment: The 500 milliseconds are just an arbitrary value. You could choose any number and the time between updating `count` changes accordingly.